# Cannot call the sort method in my quicksort implementation

Tags: java, quicksort, static-methods

I'm trying to code the quick sort algorithm using java. My problem is, that i cannot call the `sort` method. This is my code:

```
public class quickSort
{

int  partition(int a[], int left, int right)
{
    int i= left, j= right, temp;
    int pivot=a[j];
    //System.out.println(pivot+"pivot");
    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(a[i]<pivot)
            i++;
        while(a[j-1]>pivot)
            j++;

        if(i<j)
        {
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j-1];
            a[j-1]=temp;
            System.out.println(a[i] +"i");
            System.out.println(a[j-1] +"j");
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(j);
    return i;
}
int[] sort(int[] numbers, int left, int right)
{
    int x = partition(numbers, left, right);
    System.out.println(x +"Qi");
    if(left < right)
        sort(numbers, left, x-1);
        sort(numbers, x+1, right);
    return numbers; 
}


public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    quickSort q= new quickSort();

    int[] numbers = {2,6,4,9,7,0,1,3,5}; 
    int left = 0, right=numbers.length-1;
    q.sort(numbers, left, right);
    }
}
```

problem:

```
sort(numbers, left, x-1);
sort(numbers, x+1, right);
```

this recursion is not getting executed

It also results in an out of bounds exception, when i try to code in the partition method.

This is a screenshot of the output I m using it just to display the output and show the IDE I used to execute :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j6lHuEONZkO_Dr3ZszoPKh4bNXZgkgbT/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: I've tried the exact same code as you provided and it works fine for me. Please provide any error codes/messages you get when you try to compile/run the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "main quick sort method could not be called"? How are you trying to run this code? Are you getting any errors/exceptions/incorrect results?

Comment: Please update your question to include the error message you are receiving.

Comment: this is a link of screenshot of the execution:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j6lHuEONZkO_Dr3ZszoPKh4bNXZgkgbT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: stop pasting links to images and start including proper content in the question please. If you must , paste image not link to some external sources.

Comment: By the way, it looks like you're using Java 1.6. That's ancient and has been out of official support for years. The current version of Java is 11.

Answer (score 0):

The current code produces in the partition-method either an endless loop or an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException depending on your choosen numbers-array. A possible fix is e.g.:

```
private int partition(int a[], int left, int right) {
    int i = left, j = right, temp;
    int pivot = a[j];
    while (i <= j) {
        if (a[i] > pivot) {
            temp = a[i];
            for (int k = i; k < right; k++) { // remove a[i] and move all elements...
                a[k] = a[k + 1];              // ...following a[i] to the left
            }
            j--;                              // decrement pivot's index
            a[right] = temp;                  // move a[i] to the right end
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return j;                                 // return pivot's modified index
}
```

Furthermore, in the sort-method you have to ensure for **both** recursive sort-calls that the left boundary is smaller than the right boundary, e.g.:

```
private int[] sort(int[] numbers, int left, int right) {
    int x = partition(numbers, left, right);
    if (left < right) { // left boundary smaller than right one
        sort(numbers, left, x - 1);
        sort(numbers, x + 1, right); 
    }
    return numbers;
}
```